# Is it possible to use the switch method to match 2 Strings together?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, switch-statement

I have 16 strings a user can choose from being passed as variables from a previous VC to the current VC but the user must choose **only 2 strings**. 
The name of the variables are `startingLength` and `endingLength` these variables are the 2 chosen strings from the 16 of the previous VC.
I would like to use the switch method to determine what would happen if certain strings match however Im getting this error.

*Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Bool'*

Here is my code.

```swift
    import UIKit

    class LengthOutputViewController: UIViewController {


        @IBOutlet weak var lengthOutputLabel: UILabel!

        //MARK: LENGTH VARS
        var startingLength = String()
        var endingLength = String()
        var lengthTextFieldValue = Double()
        var output = Double()



        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


        }
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

            switch startingLength || endingLength { // Error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Bool'
            case :"Feet" || "Inches" // Error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Bool'



            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In switch method based on [Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html) you can compare 1 variable but with many values.

So you can compaire  `startingLength` with `"Feet" || "Inches"` and `endingLength` with `"Feet" || "Inches"` but not in the same switch case.

So one way to do that with switch case is to pass the string value that is stored from startingLength and endingLength in a function that aplies the switch case effects. 
**example**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       self.testString(string: startingLength)
       self.testString(string: endingLength)
    }

  private func testString(string: String) {
       switch string {
           case "Feet", "Inches":
         // Do what supposed to happen
           break
           default:
              break
       }
  }
```

Comment: What if i want to add another `case "Feet","Nanometer":` I get a warning saying *Literal value is already handled by previous pattern; consider removing it*

Comment: Yes becase it will enter the first case with "Feet" or "Nanometer" and will not enter the second. You can achive the same result by adding more lines in  "//Do what supposed to happen" in my example until the "break"

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        switch (startingLength , endingLength) {
        case  ("Feet",  "Inches"):
            print("test")

        default : break
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't test 2 seperate values, it creates a tuple with these two values. It's wrong. The case were startingLength is equal to "Inches" will not pass..